# Has anyone successfully use JPype to load the Netflix photon classes?

Tags: java, python, netflix, jpype

I built the Netflix Photon docker image from https://github.com/Netflix/photon and it works as in I am able to launch a container and run the provided java applications.

On top of this I installed Python3, gcc, and JPype1-py3 but am unable to load the Photon java classes.

I can launch the JVM successfully using:

> > > startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=/source/build/libs")
> > >       java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")
> > >           Hello World

So I know the JVM itself is working but whenever I try to load a class from Photon I get an error:

```
>>> s = JClass("com.netflix.imflibrary.st2067_2.ImpAsset")
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 55, in JClass
  raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXEC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class com.netf;ox/imflibrary.st2067_2.IMPAsset not found
```

Has anyone been able to integrate directly  with the Netflix photon classes using JPype? I would rather not be limited to running the provided applications through subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

crickets!??

Ok, I figured it out anyway, had to load the jar files like this:

```
try:
    from jpype import *
    classpath="/source/build/libs/Photon-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/source/build/libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/source/build/libs/regxmllib-1.1.1.jar:/source/build/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/source/build/libs/jsr305-3.0.1.jar:/source/build/libs/log4j.properties:/source/build/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"
    startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
    print("JVM started: ",getDefaultJVMPath())
    print("classpath=",classpath)
except Exception as e:
print("error launching JVM:", traceback.format_exc())
exit()

print("Starting scan of",scanfolder)
IMPAnalyzer = JClass("com.netflix.imflibrary.app.IMPAnalyzer")
IMPFile = java.io.File(scanfolder)
error_fatal = 0
error_nonfatal = 0
error_warning = 0
if IMPFile.isDirectory():
    result_dict = {}
    IMPresult_iterator = IMPAnalyzer.analyzePackage(IMPFile).entrySet().iterator()
    while IMPresult_iterator.hasNext():
        resultpair = IMPresult_iterator.next()
        # print(resultpair.getKey(),":")
        if len(resultpair.getValue()) > 0:
            error_list = []
            list_iterator = resultpair.getValue().iterator()
            while list_iterator.hasNext():
                errorobject = list_iterator.next()
                error_list.append(str(errorobject.errorLevel) + ":" + str(errorobject.errorCode) + ":" + errorobject.toString())
                if str(errorobject.errorLevel) == "WARNING":
                        error_warning += 1
                elif str(errorobject.errorLevel) == "NON FATAL":
                        error_nonfatal += 1
                elif str(errorobject.errorLevel) == "FATAL":
                        error_fatal += 1
            result_dict[resultpair.getKey()] = error_list
        else:
            result_dict[resultpair.getKey()]='Ok'
    print(scanfolder,"scanned with",error_fatal,"fatal error(s),",error_nonfatal,"nonfatal error(s), and",error_warning,"warning(s)")
    pprint.pprint(result_dict)
else:
    print(scanfolder,"does not appear to be a valid folder")
```